# Swift JSON Parsing Error

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to parse my JSON response coming from rest api but constantly getting an error.

My request sending and JSON parsing code is below and also I added Xcode's error message.

I appreciate any help in advance.

My JSON format:

```
{
    "error":1,
    "name":"batuhan",
    "mail":"mymail@gmail.com",
    "password":"e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e",
    "user_type":"user"
}
```

My code:

```
@IBAction func registerButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let name: String = self.name.text!
    let mail: String = self.mail.text!
    let password: String = self.password.text!


    var responseString: String = ""

    let url = URL(string: "http://my_webserver/index.php?process=register")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "mail=\(String(describing: mail))&name=\(String(describing: name))&password=\(String(describing: password))&register_type=user"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
        }

        responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!

    }


    struct RegisteredUser: Codable {
        let error: String
        let name: String
        let mail: String
        let password: String
        let user_type: String
    }


    let jsonData = responseString.data(using: .utf8)!
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let user_data = try! decoder.decode(RegisteredUser.self, from: jsonData)

    print(user_data.name)
    print(user_data.mail)


    task.resume()
}
```

The error:

> fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}))): file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-900.0.65/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 181

Comment: If you log `jsonData` and `responseString` before you decode, what do you see?

Comment: @ItaiFerber I don't log them, even I put print(responseString) right after the line ----responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!---- it doesn't show up

Comment: Which means, then, that your code is never getting hit, and `responseString` retains its default value of `””`, which is why you can’t parse it

Comment: "No value", your response is empty? Make usefull prints: At the start of the closure, add: print("Response: \(response)"); print("Task Error: \(error)"); print("Data: \(data); \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)")`; might be helpful, but I think that you have an error somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Your questions covers the problem a bit too much, it is clearly in the JSON decode which you should have isolated. Anyways: here comes the (trivial) answer.

In your JSON-data `error`is a number and in your class definition it is a `String`.

So you have two very simple paths to solve your problem, either you should define

```
error: Int
```

in your `RegisteredUser` or you put

```
"error":"1",
```

into your `JSONdata`.

If what you showed in the beginning was returned from your web service you will have to adapt the format of your `RegisteredUser` to match the JSON-data exactly. Remember: `JSONDecoder.decode` is *very* picky, as any good parser should be.

I would generally recommend to catch errors like this and not use `try!` if you are talking to the web since there are simply too many things that can go wrong. Although I have to admit that in this case `error.localizedDescription` was not terribly helpful at

```
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
```

This did however point me in the right direction since it made me read your input more closely.

### Update (with code)

I successfully parsed your `String`in a playground as follows:

```
import Cocoa
struct RegisteredUser: Codable {
    let error: Int
    let name: String
    let mail: String
    let password: String
    let user_type: String
}

var str = """
{
"error":1,
  "name":"batuhan",
  "mail":"mymail@gmail.com",
  "password":"e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e",
  "user_type":"user"
}
"""
let jsonData = str.data(using: .utf8)!
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
    let user_data = try decoder.decode(RegisteredUser.self, from: jsonData)
    print(user_data)
} catch {
    print("error on decode: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

This prints

```
RegisteredUser(error: 1, name: "batuhan", mail: "mymail@gmail.com", password: "e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e", user_type: "user")
```

Please post the code that does not work (and what you expect it to do) if you would like us to help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, converting it String to Int does not work

Comment: `print("error on decode: \(error.localizedDescription)")` =>  `print("error on decode: \(error)")` would give more infos.